# C Puzzle - play with types

Tags: c, types, scope, declaration, puzzle

Please check the below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st
{
 int a ;
}

fn ()
{
 struct st obj ;
 obj.a = 10 ;

 return obj ;
}

int main()
{
 struct st obj = fn() ;

 printf ("%d", obj.a) ;
}
```

Following are the questions

1. What is the output of the program?
2. Where is ';' terminating the declaration of 'struct st'?

   By ISO IEC 9899 - 1999
       specification, declaration should
       end with a ';'.

   ```
       declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
   ```
3. If the declaration of the 'struct
   st' is taken representing only the return type of
   the function 'fn', how is it visible
   to other functions (main)?

Comment: Comeau complains about the missing ; after the struct and also that fn() has no return type.

Comment: Homework? ;) I think the output would be 10, formatted as decimal (I assume that's what %d means)

Comment: Specifically it says: line 3: error: type definition is not allowed in function return type declaration

Comment: @mxp I think this is C code, don't compile it as C++ code.

Comment: @AraK Oh, sorry, you're right.

Comment: Doesn't seem homework but a very deliberately confusing and strategic question. The main idea is to identify how different compilers handle the return type of a function, whether they introduce it in the scope of the application or treat it as a local notion for the function. I like this question.

Comment: Compiles with `gcc`. As AraK mentions, it's not valid C++. `g++` says: *error: new types may not be defined in a return type* / *note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of ‘st’)*.

Comment: @AraK Compiling in C99 mode it magically works. Not my day today...

Comment: I think homeworks are not yet into the calibre of giving reference to the specification. I loved the second question.

Comment: So now we can look forward to code golf on thursdays .. and syntatic puzzles on fridays? COOL!

Comment: @tinkertim take my bow!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things may be a little clearer if we reformat the code a bit:

```
struct st { int a; } fn() 
{
  struct st obj;
  obj.a = 10;
  return obj;
}
int main()
{
  struct st obj = fn();
  printf("%d\n", obj.a);
  return 0;
}
```

Thus, the return type of `fn()` is `struct st {int a;}`.  There's no semicolon after the struct definition because the struct type is part of the function definition (trace through the grammar from `translation-unit` -> `top-level-declaration` -> `function-definition`).  The struct type is available to `main()` because you put a struct tag on it (st).  Had you written

```
struct { int a; } fn() {...}
```

then the type would not have been available to `main()`; you would have had to create a new struct type with the same definition.

You get the same effect as if you had written

```
struct st {
  int a; 
};

struct st fn() 
{ 
  /* same as before */
}

int main()
{
  /* same as before */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

1. The output is 10.
2. There doesn't need to be a semicolon because the whole thing is a function definition.
3. The structure tag `st` is declared at global scope and is therefore visible to main.

Comment: 4. GCC is a little more forgiving than I thought.